# Cで木構造をつくろうとしたが、ノードの値を上手く保存できていない

Tags: c

Cで木構造をつくるにあたって，

```
//ノード
struct tnode
{
    struct tnode *left;
    char *value;
    struct tnode *right;
};

struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return (struct tnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

struct tnode *gentree(struct tnode *p, char *w)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        //端に来たら生成
        p=talloc();
        strcpy(p->value, w);
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        //端じゃないなら左右にNULLまで走査
        p->left  = gentree(p->left, w);
        p->right = gentree(p->right, w);
    }
    return p;
}

void main()
{
    struct tnode *root;
    root = NULL;

    root=gentree(root, "aaa");
    printf("%s\n", root->value);
    putchar('\n');

    root=gentree(root, "bbb");
    printf("%s\n", root->value);
    printf("%s\n", root->left->value);
    printf("%s\n", root->right->value);
}
```

このようにして作成しようとしてます.
木の構造としては，aaaが2つのbbbに分岐してほしいのですが，実行結果は

```
aaa

bbb //aaaであってほしい
bbb
bbb
```

と，どこかでaaaがbbbに書き換えられてしまいます．試しに以下のように書き換えアドレスを確認したところ，2つのアドレスは同じでした．

```
root=gentree(root, "aaa");
printf("%d\n", root);

root=gentree(root, "bbb");
printf("%d\n", root);
```

初歩的なことかもしれませんが，どうかご回答お願いいたします．

Answer (score 1):

えっと、ほんとに動きます？

```
//ノード
struct tnode
{
    struct tnode *left;
    char *value;
    struct tnode *right;
};
```

valueがポインタで割当されてません。

手っ取り早い（効率等まるっと無視)のは、

```
strcpy(p->value, w);
```

の前に

```
p->value = malloc((strlen(w) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

することですね。

メモリ割り当て複数回すると効率がーとか考え出すなら裏技として

```
//ノード
struct tnode
{
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
    char value[0];
};

struct tnode *talloc(size_t val_size)
{
    return (struct tnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode) + sizeof(char) * val_size);
}
```

なんて方法もあります。

Comment: 補足: C言語において `sizeof(char)` は常に `1` なので、分かりやすさ以外の意味で掛け算する必要はありません。([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215445/5989200))